How can I clone a complex, dual boot disk? 22.04
My new SSD is defective. Surprising, but I've been all over it and that's my conclusion. Sometimes dd'ing to /dev/null errs out, sometimes it passes. I've arranged for a factory replacement.
Meanwhile I'd like to clone my installation to an SSD from a different manufacturer.
Luckily this other SSD has a few 1,000 more sectors.
My partition scheme is relatively complex, with separate partitions for /, /boot, /var, and swap. It is also dual boot with Win11. I think it's also got an installation of Ubuntu 23.*  as well.
I've faced somewhat similar issues before. My approach would be loosely as follows:

Boot from a USB drive into the live try/install environment.
dd from the old disk to the new  disk
If dd fails repeatedly, dd the individual partitions and get down and dirty with rsync etc: But actually i have a (somewhat stale) dd image on an external drive, which proceeded without error.
Fiddle a bit with grub2. My experience has been it's pretty clever about detecting both the linux and windows partitions.
Cram some values into UEFI through the BIOS.

Two questions:
Am i missing something?
And, is there a canned utility or script that will accomplish the same thing? I've read answers pointing to such solutions, but not in the context of a complex partition/dual boot scheme.
Take care always,
-jeffro

Seems like it should work, but you might get a cleaner copy  from the file system level.  Not sure how an SSD handles replacement blocks, but the redirections and fragmentation would be carried over by dd to the new system.

I share your concern. But the defective disk in question defies all normal means of analysis and repair, If only because it's failure is intermittent. I'm not particularly concerned about fragmentation, and as far as I can tell the device exhibits toxic immunity with respect to redirection.

look at the ddrescue tool before you do anything else
